# Is it possible to echo the data into a textbox or save this data on MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to echo the data into a textbox and save this data on MySQL?

```
Here is the code:


    <!-- score -->

    <div class="score">
    <b id='boldStuff_1'>0</b><br />
    </div><!-- end score -->

//below is a textbox wherein I would like to echo the score

<input type="text" name="name">
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You should add more details to your question. The answer at the moment would be something like: "yepp, it's possible"

Comment: <input type="text" name="name">

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>"/>
```

And to save in DB use

```
$_REQUEST['name']
```

Comment: ERROR:  <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: score in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\The_adventures_of_juan1\adventures\Burnham.php</b> on line <b>486</b><br />

Comment: JS:<!--score-->
<script type="text/javascript">

var score_black = 0;

document.onkeydown = key_control;

function remove_score_black(){
 score_black-=50;
 
 document.getElementById('boldStuff_1').innerHTML = score_black;
}
function add_score_black(){
 score_black+=100;
 
 document.getElementById('boldStuff_1').innerHTML = score_black;
}



</script> 
<!-- end score-->
//I've added your codes   <!-- score --><div class="score">
<b id='boldStuff_1'>0</b><br />
</div><!-- end score -->
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $score; ?>"/>

Comment: Just see your code where is PHP variable $score. What are you trying to do ?? Say clearly and update your code.

Comment: It's really hard to explain.Can I send you the .zip file?